# iOS: Multiple GMail send-form addresses, using S/MIME

Tags: ios, gmail, mobile-mail

I tried to setup my GMail-Account *including my various send-as-addresses* that I set up in the Webmail interface using [this great tutorial](http://modernerd.com/post/535350679/solved-gmail-ipad-iphone-and-multiple-from).

However, I have two issues:

1. I cannot setup multiple S/MIME signing certificates, so only one address can send signed mails.
2. The iPhone has it's own idea which address should be the default from-Address.

Is there any way to setup a GMail-Account so there is one inbox, multiple send-as-addresses and an S/MIME-signing-certificate set up for each address, and a user-selectable default address? Apple Mail on OS X can do that.

Comment: Default `from` account for Mail can be set in `Settings->Mail->Default Account`, just below Signature setting.

Comment: That's right - but I only have one Account. I do have multiple addresses, but they're all assigned to the same account.